# Repository Design Pattern in Laravel4.1 - Retriving all data

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hi All following are the details of my problem : Am able to create resource but not able to retrieve all resources.

**RepositoryInterface**

```
<?php
namespace Repo\Repositories\RepoInterfaces;

/**
* RepositoryInterface provides the standard functions to be expected of ANY
* repository.
*/
interface RepositoryInterface {

/**
* @param array $attributes
* @return mixed
*/
public function create(array $attributes);

/**
* @param array $columns
* @return mixed
*/
public function all($columns = array('*'));

}
```

**Abstract**

```
<?php
namespace Repo\Abstracts;

use Repo\Repositories\RepoInterfaces\RepositoryInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;

/**
* The Abstract Repository provides default implementations of the methods defined
* in the base repository interface. These simply delegate static function calls
* to the right eloquent model based on the $modelClassName.
*/

abstract class Repository implements RepositoryInterface {

/**
* @var
*/
protected $modelClassName;

/**
* @param array $attributes
* @return mixed
*/
public function create(array $attributes)
{
return call_user_func_array("{$this->modelClassName}::create", array($attributes));
}

/**
* @param array $columns
* @return mixed
*/
public function all($columns = array('*'))
{
return call_user_func_array("{$this->modelClassName}::all", array($columns));
}
}
```

**VehicleManufacturerRepositoryInterface**

```
<?php
namespace Repo\Repositories\RepoInterfaces;

/**
* The VehicleManufacturerRepositoryInterface contains ONLY method signatures for methods
* related to the VehicleManufacturer object.
*
* Note that we extend from RepositoryInterface, so any class that implements
* this interface must also provide all the standard eloquent methods (find, all, etc.)
*/

interface VehicleManufacturerRepositoryInterface extends RepositoryInterface {

}
```

**VehicleManufacturerInterface**

```
<?php
namespace Repo\Repositories;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as DB;
use Repo\Abstracts\Repository as AbstractRepository;
use Repo\Repositories\RepoInterfaces\VehicleManufacturerRepositoryInterface;

class VehicleManufacturerRepository extends AbstractRepository implements VehicleManufacturerRepositoryInterface
{
/**
* @var string
*/
protected $modelClassName = 'VehicleManufacturer';
}
```

**VehicleManufacturerController**

```
<?php
use Repo\Repositories\VehicleManufacturerRepository AS Vmanf;

class VehicleManufacturerController extends \BaseController {

public function __construct(Vmanf $vmanf)
{
$this->vmanf = $vmanf;
}

/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return Response
*/
public function index()
{
$results = $this->vmanf->all(array('*'));
return Response::json(array('status'=>true,'data' => $results));
}

/**
* Store a newly created resource in storage.
*
* @return Response
*/
public function store()
{
$inputData = array (
'caption' => Input::get('caption'),
'image' => Input::get('image'),
);
if($this->vmanf->create($inputData)) {
return Response::json(array('status' => true));
} else {
return Response::json(array('status' => false,'msg' => 'Vehicle Manufacturer Not saved'));
}
}
}
```

> THE Results are The store function in controller works but index
>   function gives following result  {"status":true,"data":{}}